# Array in Vue method is very slow?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In html:

```
<div @mouseenter='setDisplay(0)' @mouseleave='setHide(0)'
  <div
    class="innerHolder"
    v-show='innerDisplay[0]'
    >
    aaa
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use v-show and array to control the whether the div shows.
And in data:

```
innerDisplay: [false,flase,false]
```

Then in methods:

```
setDisplay(index){
  this.innerDisplay[index] = true;
},
setHide(index){
  this.innerDisplayArray[index] = false;
},
```

**Strange, it works,but very slow. This 'slow' means when my mouse enter the parent div for about 5 second, the child div will show.** But if i use this:

```
v-show:'innerDisplay'
```

and in data i use:

```
innerDisplay: false;
```

and the mouseenter event just changes the boolean rahter than the array of boolean, **the child div will show up the moment mouse moves in in just a second**

Is the array slowing down the methods?

Comment: I don't know the heck about Vue, but I think it can be something with change detection causing it. I would try changing the methods setDisplay and setHide to create a new array, like:

    setDisplay(index) {
      this.innerDisplay = this.innerDisplay.map((e, i) => i === index ? true : e);
    }

    setHide(index) {
      this.innerDisplayArray= this.innerDisplayArray.map((e, i) => i === index ? true   : e);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [change detection](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue

You need to use `$set`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    innerDisplay: [false, false, false]
  },
  methods: {
    setDisplay(index) {
      this.$set(this.innerDisplay, index, true);
    },
    setHide(index) {
      this.$set(this.innerDisplay, index, false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @mouseenter='setDisplay(0)' @mouseleave='setHide(0)'>
    <h1>Before</h1>
    <div class="innerHolder" v-show='innerDisplay[0]'>
      aaa
    </div>
    <h1>After</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!(●'◡'●)ﾉ♥

Comment: what is the equivalent of this for vue3?

Comment: Looks like Vue 3 handles it without any special behavior.
 https://medium.com/@mario.brendel1990/vue-3-change-detection-caveats-7e09125647c1